# How to reinstall "System Settings" app on Elementary OS - 5.1?

Tags: release-hera, settings, software-installation, appcenter, pantheon

I removed "System Settings" app from elementary, and I tried to reinstall with the appcenter but it didn't download :( 
Please help me.

Comment: No problem, I resolved it.

Comment: You can try to recompile all the app with VALA and ninja:

Comment: LINK: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard

Comment: Compiling and installing it this way means that you won't receive updates for these components in the future.

You can install switchboard from the terminal with `sudo apt install switchboard` and then the plugs are called things like `switchboard-plug-sound` etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to recompile the app, it doesn't call "System Setting", the app name is Switchboard, so just go to the Elementary OS github and check the repo of this app (https://github.com/elementary/switchboard ),
1) Download the repo
2) Install all the libraries and dependencies
3) Compile the project with vala and ninja
4) DONE ! :D